# Displaying LinkdIn feeds update to SharePoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to display LinkedIn Newsfeeds to SharePoint Page?

Comment: You mean user feeds?

Comment: yes,  the feed updates that comes when we login

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we cannot retrieve the user's feeds from LinkedIn.

Currently LinkedIn only provide facility to work with Company data.

You can find all the available API link that LinkedIn provide [here](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin)

For more information you can get the available services from LinkedIn [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs)